# Highcharts line chart doesn't render when sql returns more than 121 rows

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have to render a line chart with varying number of series based on the number of checkboxes selected (each checkbox name is displayed as a series in line chart). I observed that the moment sql is returning more than 121 rows for two series, line chart doesn't render.

I am creating json based on the number of columns (number of checkboxes selected) in my sql query. I tried adding turboThreshold but to no avail. Below is code for creating json and highchart:

```
function f() {
var json = "";
var j = "";
var fcol = [];
var cols = [];
var collen = "";

var one = [];
var two = [];
var three = [];
var four = [];
var five = [];

var six = [];
var seven = [];
var eight = [];
var nine = [];
var ten = [];

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j == 0) {
            fcol.push(result[i][0]);
      }
}
//alert(fcol);
fcol = JSON.stringify(fcol);
  for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        collen = result[i].length;
        //alert(result[i].length);
      for(j = 1; j < result[i].length; j++) {
          cols.push(this.metadata[j]['colName']);
        }
        cols = cols.slice(0,collen-1);
    }
//alert(cols);
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 1) {
            one.push(result[i][1]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 2) {
            two.push(result[i][2]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 3) {
            three.push(result[i][3]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 4) {
            four.push(result[i][4]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 5) {
            five.push(result[i][5]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 6) {
            six.push(result[i][6]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 7) {
            seven.push(result[i][7]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 8) {
            eight.push(result[i][8]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 9) {
            nine.push(result[i][9]);
      }
}

for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (j = 10) {
            ten.push(result[i][10]);
      }
}
var marr = [];
marr.push(one);
marr.push(two);
marr.push(three);
//alert('three'+marr);
marr.push(four);
//alert('four'+marr);
marr.push(five);

marr.push(six);
marr.push(seven);
marr.push(eight);
marr.push(nine);
marr.push(ten);

**for(i = 0; i < collen-1; i++) {
            if (i == (collen-2)) {
                json+='{"name":"'+cols[i]+'","data":['+marr[i]+']}';
                }
            else {
                json+='{"name":"'+cols[i]+'","data":['+marr[i]+']},';
                }
}
var y = "["+json+"]";**

 $('#iChartMultiStationReport').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'iChartMultiStationReport',
            type: 'line',
            margin: 75,
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Line Chart'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Testing'
        },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: $.parseJSON(fcol),//$.parseJSON($("body").data("xaxis"))
                    labels: {   align: 'left',
                                            x: -5,
                                            y: 65,
                                            style: {
                                                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                                fontSize: '8pt',
                                                color: '#000000',
                                                //textOverflow:'none', //I changed these two lines
                                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap'

                                            }
                                        }
            },
        **plotOptions: {
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 10000000000
            }
        },**
                series: $.parseJSON(y)//$.parseJSON($("body").data("yaxis"))
                //$.parseJSON(document.getElementById('container').getAttribute('yaxis'))

    });
}
```

Please provide your valuable inputs. Thank you.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't have any limits per points/series. It is probably something wrong with the data (like corrupted data, strings in the date etc.). Do you have any errors in JavaScript console? Also could you setup jsFiddle with that issue? With static data for 121 rows.

Comment: yeah this is likely data that contains unescaped quotes etc that render the javascript invalid. Check the browser's console

Answer (score 0):

Highchart does not have any limitations for the number of lines.

The whole line-chart does not render or only some of the lines are rendered?
If some lines are rendered, then check if there are any null values in the data that you are passing to highchart for the missing lines

Note: A jsfiddle might help to resolve your issue in an efficient way.

Comment: After digging, I found out that it's not the issue with the number of rows returned by the query. The issue occurs if first value of any series is null. Here's jsfiddle link for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/d2uwaxox/3/           Change the first value of any series data to blank. The chart doesn't come up. If we add "null" string in place of balnk value, it works.